# timer & overflow interrupt MikroC code

Tags: avr, atmega, mikroc

```
void TimerFunction()
{
TIMSK=(1<<TOIE0);
TCNT0=0x00;
TCCR0 |= (0<<CS02) | (1<<CS00) | (0<<CS01);
}

//##############################################################################
ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    // process the timer0 overflow here
  countClock ++;
  count++;
  delay++;
//some extra code 
}
```

then

```
void main()
{
 //someCode
 TimerFunction();
}
```

but it doesnt work for me ,so is that the right way to start the timer 0 and its interrupt service routine ??

Answer (score 0):

At first sight I'd say you miss

```
sei();  // set global interrupt flag
```

if this is not within `//someCode` ... in any case I recommend turning on the global interrupt enable flag only after initializing all specific interrupt sources (timers, USART, etc)

Comment: undeclared indentifier "sei" expression

Comment: `sei()` is normally defined in `<avr/interrupt.h>` ... have you `#include` d that?

Comment: i use Mikro C for avr compiler as i know there is no #include in it

Comment: then try to use `SREG_I = 1;`

Comment: maybe SREG_I is the position of the bit within the SREG ... sorry I am not familiar with MikroC - using AVR Studio ... anyway - you need to set the global interrupt enable bit which is bit 7 of the AVR status register

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your code global interrupt flag is not set. If solutions which purposed MikeD are not working, try this:

```
asm{sei};
```

Answer (score 0):

use  SREG.SREG_I = 1; to enable global interrupts